# dictionary manipulation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new to pandas and i am having difficulties working with dictionaries within pandas.

```
     primary_tags           MOT_tag_name
0   {"home_tags":"4"}     Bus,Bicycle,Ferry,Car
1   {"home_tags":"7"}     Bus,Ferry,Taxi
2   {"home_tags":"71"}    Bus,Bus,Car
3   {"home_tags":"46"}    Bicycle,Bus
4   {"home_tags":"32"}    Bicycle
```

How can I extract the dictionary values in the `primary_tags` column and explode the `MOT_tag_name` for the dataframe to look like this.

```
     primary_tags           MOT_tag_name
0                 4       Bus
1                 4       Bicycle
2                 4       Ferry
3                 4       Car
4                 7       Bus
5                 7       Ferry
6                 7       Taxi
7                71       Bus
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) and [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) first, so is possible use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) by splitted values to lists:

```
df['primary_tags'] = df['primary_tags'].str.get('home_tags')
df['MOT_tag_name'] = df['MOT_tag_name'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('MOT_tag_name').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or:

```
df = (df.assign(primary_tags = df['primary_tags'].str.get('home_tags'),
                MOT_tag_name = df['MOT_tag_name'].str.split(','))
        .explode('MOT_tag_name')
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
print (df)
   primary_tags MOT_tag_name
0             4          Bus
1             4      Bicycle
2             4        Ferry
3             4          Car
4             7          Bus
5             7        Ferry
6             7         Taxi
7            71          Bus
8            71          Bus
9            71          Car
10           46      Bicycle
11           46          Bus
12           32      Bicycle
```